# extracting trending hashtags via Twitter API

Tags: python, twitter, hashtag, tweepy

I'm using the following code to run a twitter bot that should use a hashtag that is at top of trends at the moment of tweeting and the bot uses it to Tweet thoughts of famous philosophers.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import tweepy, time, sys 

argfile = str(sys.argv[1])

#enter the corresponding information from your Twitter application:
CONSUMER_KEY = 'secret'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'secret'
ACCESS_KEY = 'secret'
ACCESS_SECRET = 'secret'
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

filename=open(argfile,'r')
f=filename.readlines()
filename.close()

trends1 = api.trends_place(1)
print trends1
hashtags = [x['name'] for x in trends1[0]['trends'] if x['name'].startswith('#')]
# print hashtags
print hashtags[0]
trend_hashtag = hashtags[0]

# Tweet every X min ...
for line in f:
    api.update_status(line + ' ' + trend_hashtag)
    time.sleep(1800)
```

The problem is that the code permanently stores the trending hashtag that it retrieved in the first iteration. How can I achieve that the hashtag will be extracted anew for every tweet (in this case, every 1800 sec)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

The obvious change is to update the hashtags *inside* your loop:

```
for line in f:
    trends1 = api.trends_place(1)
    print trends1
    hashtags = [x['name'] for x in trends1[0]['trends'] if x['name'].startswith('#')]
    # print hashtags
    print hashtags[0]
    trend_hashtag = hashtags[0]
    api.update_status("{0} {1}".format(line, trend_hashtag)) # more modern format
    time.sleep(1800)
```

Comment: oh that seems easy, will give it a try tnx!